# Why do I need to escape dollar sign in single quotes?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell strings in single quotes are supposed to ignore special characters inside. But why I need to escape dollar sign if I'm using `-match`?

```
$Src = '$SOMETHING$'         # Good
$Src                         # Good, returns string as is
$Src -match '$SOMETHING$'    # Returns false if $ is not escaped
$Src -match '\$SOMETHING\$'  # Returns true, $ is escaped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `-match` using regex to match your string and `$` is regex character that you need to escape...

Consider using `[regex]::escape`:

```
$Src = '$SOMETHING$'; #Good
$Src -match [regex]::escape('$SOMETHING$')
```