# How to add a variable of which the value contains a $-sign?

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I have a piece of code that connects to an ESXi server and retrieves some information. Now i have an issue in that i run it remotely on alot of different ESXi's.
This means that my password is a variable in the script ($env:ESXPassword) .. the problem comes here however. 
When a password has a dollarsign in it, it sees a part of the password as variable, but when i put it in single quotes or use any of the other recommendations.. it does not see the $env:ESXPassword as variable anymore and it wont inject the correct password.
There is no way for me to put the password itself in the script as it simply changes depending on the customer i run it on remotely though my MSP software.

I am hoping i am just missing something very obvious/logical.

So far ive tried:
- Single quotes
- Escaping it using an escape character like the backtick
- Letting it read the password out of a text file (just as test though as this is clearly not safe enough)

Sadly none of the options worked.

```
$secureStringPwd = $env:ESXPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$user = $env:ESXUser
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd
Connect-VIServer -Server $env:ESXName -Protocol https -Credential $creds
```

When it takes a password using a $ sign, it puts it in as that. For example Pa$word it will give the error that $word does not contain any information in combination with it saying the password "Pa" is wrong.

I want it ofcourse to see the Pa$word as the password and allow it to connect.

edit: edited away some quotes that were not needed as can be seen by the comment of AdminOfThings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to ecape dollar sign in single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589265/why-do-i-need-to-ecape-dollar-sign-in-single-quotes) ... If not a duplicate, at least it will show you how to escape the dollar sign to get it to work.

Comment: Not really. Those topics are mostly all about escaping text that is added into the script itself. What i need to do is somehow not escape the first variable (that contains the password with the $ in it) so that its seen as a variable. This way it adds in the password which then needs to be escaped so it can be used. My issue happens already before it has to match or do anything with the password itself

Comment: You don't need quotes around your variables in your posted example. `$env:ESXPassword` here does mean you have an environment variable called `ESXPassword` rather than `$env:ESXPassword` being the actual password, correct?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Correct to both remarks. The endresult doesnt change without the quotes but i do agree on them having no use there. And yes, the idea is that the enviromental variable ESXPassword changes into a password.. and that password has a $ in it. So the problem is that if i escape/single quote stuff.. the ESXPassword variable wont change into the password as its not seen as variable anymore. But if it stays a variable, i cant really escape the password being seen as a variable due to it having a $ in it

Comment: It ***seems*** like the variable is being used in different way than the provided example. Depending on which application/executable interacts with this variable, the escape sequence may vary. The PowerShell escape character is backtick. For whatever reason, you could just do a string replace before your code needs the variable contents: ```$env:esxpassword.Replace('$','`$')```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. What happens when you decrypt the password? [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): `$env:ESXPassword = 'Pa$word'; $User = 'User';$secureStringPwd = $env:ESXPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ;$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd; $creds.GetNetworkCredential().password`

Comment: @AdminOfThings Well, to be honest i think most of the issue is caused by how simple (and at the same time dumb) the software i use to remotely run these scripts throws in the variable. I get the feeling that it just throws them in nilly willy while adding normal quotes around everything. At least ... how simple your answer was, i actually did not think of that at all. And to be precise... your solution actually did work. Switching around when and when not to have the backticks using the replace command actually allowed me to make it work. So my deepest gratitude.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Will you have to add your comment as answer for me to accept it or will i not be able to yet? (Kinda new to Stackoverflow, sorry)

Comment: @PatrickB, I posted an answer. Thanks

Comment: @iRon Yeah, sadly its not really reproducable by hand as the software itself just throws in the variable while running and probably does it in the dumbest way with quotes and everything. Anyway, thanks for taking your time to think with us regardless. AdminOfThings posted a comment that actually worked around the issue in an easy way i can live with and can use to make it all run as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which application/executable interacts with this variable, the escape sequence may vary. The PowerShell escape character is backtick. If necessary, you could just do a string replace before your code needs the variable contents. The following will replace the `$` with the PowerShell escaped equivalent `` `$ ``:

```
 $env:ESXPassword.Replace('$','`$')
```